# Grabbing the selected radio button value in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

I was to trying to get the value of checked radio button form the 4 radio buttons (same name). This is all inside the functional component. But getting some trouble to get the values.

```
{details.map(questions => {
            const { counter, question, option1, option2, option3, option4, crr_option } = questions

            return (
                <div key={counter}>
                    <h2>{counter}. {question}</h2>
                    <div className="q-cont">
                        <div className="radio-cont">
                            <label htmlFor="op1">{option1}</label>
                            <input label={option1} type="radio" name="op" id="op1" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="radio-cont">
                            <label htmlFor="op2">{option2}</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="op" id="op2" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="radio-cont">
                            <label htmlFor="op3">{option3}</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="op" id="op3" />
                        </div>
                        <div className="radio-cont">
                            <label htmlFor="op4">{option4}</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="op" id="op" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        })}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple, you need to provide a `value` attribute and an `onClick` listener, to each of the radio buttons, to gather the results. I have created a minimal working example here:

[Handling click events of radio-buttons in React](https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-cache-iytu6)